# NSThread: Selector not found

Tags: cocoa, swift

I'm a bit confused why my NSThread cannot be instantiated using a selector due to a runtime error

```
target does not implement selector (*** -[FileSearcher processFilesAsync:])
```

The function is defined like this

```
func processFilesAsync(#data: [String])
```

and the NSThread will be created this way:

```
NSThread(target: self, selector: "processFilesAsync:", object: itemsPerThread[i])
```

"itemsPerThread" is just a dictionary with a String-Array as values.

As far as I know this should work as the method I want to invoke defines an argument and the selector I pass into NSThread's init() method indicates that the target method expects exactly one argument.

I already tried using Swift's "Selector" type instead of only a string but this didn't work as well. I also tried to change the method's type from "[String]" to "AnyObject" which didn't work, too.

Does anybody have a clue what might be wrong?

All of the code above lies within the same class.

I'm using Xcode 6 Beta 5.

**Edit**
I figured out that is has to do something with the parameter. I implemented a dummy method without parameters and tried to set this as target and it worked. As soon as I modified it to use a parameter as well -> same as above.

Comment: Any reason you are trying to use NSThread instead of GCD ?

Comment: I tried GCD. As there may be hundreds of thousands of files to be processed I want to try another approach: process them in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. All I had to do was to change the parameter's type from `AnyObject` to `AnyObject?`. It even works with *specialised types* (in my case `[String]?` instead of `[String]`).

Of course, because you can call it `nil` as parameter...